# ListModel containing data property of delegate

Tags: qt, qml

is it possible to create a GridView in qml which its childs defined in model, so i can have a complete dynamic child view for my GridView items, for example i want to have 10 different rectangle defined in model to be data of my delegate.
for this ,i want to create a GridView and set delegate's `data` property from model

```
GridView {
    model: ListModel{
        ListElement{
            childs:Item{ 
                // data is a list<Object> , so item here is wrong
                //this part is wrong i am looking for correct way of doing this
                //error : cannot contain nested elements 
                Button{

                }
                Button{

                }
            }
        }
    }

    delegate: Rectangle{
        data:childs
    }
}
```

this code explains logic of my question. but its not correct.
my model items will be inside rectangle but its childs are completly dynamic it could be 100 items which i dont know about them.
or another approach to ask this question is "Can i have a Component inside ListModel?"
**update**
so if i want to use this it will end up like this "lets say file name is MyWidget" :

```
MyWidget{
    model:ListModel{
       //and here we go how can i set data of GridView's delegate
    }

}
```

Comment: I guess you don't want only Rectangle, since then you could just encapsulate the properties in the ListModel instead of the Rectangles themself?

Comment: @Amfasis think of it as a GridView of Cards which content of Cards are dynamic

Comment: Ok, I see. Maybe you want to try this approach: https://forum.qt.io/topic/80826/dynamic-delegate-in-repeater/4

Comment: @Amfasis if i use loader then i should define component for every childs , which is not dynamic , as i understand from this solution

Comment: So, where does your model come from, who populates it? If like in your example it's from QML then I personally don't see a difference, but if it's from C++ it's a different story, but in that case you could create the components themself (see https://forum.qt.io/topic/42087/create-and-control-a-qml-component-from-c/2)

Comment: @Amfasis check `update` part

Comment: Well, I think you're out of luck here. Maybe you can implement it using C++ and a delegate, but then I'm not even sure either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just stumbled upon the `ObjectModel` defined in `QtQml.Models` (through another [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57263432/how-can-i-apply-delegate-of-repeater-for-objectmodel-in-qml) posted today). I had some try and came up with this solution, which is not ideal, but would get you a fair amount of what you want, I think.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQml.Models 2.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ObjectModel {
        id: obj_model
        Rectangle {
            width: 10
            height: 10
            color: "#00ffff"
        }
        Rectangle {
            width: 10
            height: 10
            color: "#ff00ff"
        }
    }

    GridView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: grid2.count

        delegate: Rectangle {
            x: 5
            y: 5
            height: 90
            width: 90
            color: "red"
        }
    }

    GridView {
        id: grid2
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: obj_model
    }
}
```

This works because the `GridView`'s have the same `cellHeight` and `cellWidth` (implicitly, you can tie them together) and are positioned the same.

This can't be perfect since the ObjectModel stops the usage of the delegate in `grid2` (Which was also the answer on the before-mentioned SO-question)

Comment: that was what i'm looking for `ObjectModel` ty